# Are there any monitors with little to no ghosting?

Tags: display, refresh-rate, 120hz

For example like on below image. Are there any monitors that have zero ghosting, or at least like 1 or 2 mouse trails like in the image I linked? I've never owned a 1 ms monitor, the lowest I've owned was a 144 hz 4 ms monitor, and it was full of noticeable ghosting.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What you are experiencing is not ghosting, its most likely a mouse trail setting on your OS or maybe a very slow computer or buggy driver.  Even an entry level LCD monitor will not have ghosting as there is a 1:1 mapping between pixels and monitor output.

(Also, your question is dangerously close to  "Product Recommendation" question which is off-topic here)

Comment: I think he was using mouse trails as an example for ghosting.

Comment: @Keltari Correct its just an example, try it for yourelf, spin the mouse in circles and you'll see the trail caused by the monitor. + it not a "Product Recommendation" at all, Im trying to figure out if a zero ghosting monitor exists or if its even possible to achieve zero ghosting.

Comment: @PolisP2  None of the systems I use (and its a few) show mouse trails caused by the monitor - where the monitors are generally cheap business office monitors.  I am pretty sure what you are describing is not ghosting, rather it is either a software setting or a graphics card or driver issue.  "Ghosting" actually means a secondary signal caused by distortion of the [ analog ] input which causes a lighter version of the image to be superimposed on the screen, offset or blurred out from the main image.

Comment: Also, at 4ms, the image would remain 1/250th of a second after it was removed.  No way you could move a typical mouse that much.   Also, unless you are gaming (and even then), the difference between a 1ms and 5ms monitor is probably imperceptible.  What graphics card do you have, and what programs are you running where "ghosting" occurs?

Comment: Im not interested in purchasing a monitor, I was just wondering, is zero ghosting possible, I play fortnite, and due to the ghosting on 4ms 144hz, the last few frames remain a little too long, so when Im moving the screen really fast when Im shooting, the one enemy I see now becomes 3 enemys, and Im very bad at the game just because of that. watch this, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6g85vqdK2A is it possible for a monitor to have none of that or at least a little? the monitor I purchased was soo cheap for 144hz Im starting to wonder if the 4ms is a lie, ED242QR $160 on amazon.

Comment: As stated you are attributing problems not caused by the monitor to it. The video does not show ghosting despite its incorrect title. (for a start ghosting is an analog issue caused by reflected signals in the analog path, what you are seeing is digital and only affects foreground images being redrawn by the graphics card)